# Como poner un nuevo modelo a un JTree en Swing

Tags: java, java-swing

Creo un `JTree` desde la vista de diseño de *Swing*, **ya que es obligatorio para el ejercicio**, luego pongo el siguiente código que muestro, vuelvo a ejecutar la aplicación, pero no aparece el nuevo modelo creado. Alguien sabe como funciona esto?

```
    root = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Root");
    DefaultMutableTreeNode bancos = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Bancos");
    DefaultMutableTreeNode cajas_ahorro = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Cajas de Ahorro");

    DefaultMutableTreeNode bbva = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("BBVA");
    DefaultMutableTreeNode sabadell = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Sabadell");
    DefaultMutableTreeNode santander = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Santander");
    DefaultMutableTreeNode suizo = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Suizo");
    DefaultMutableTreeNode deutche = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Deutche Bank");
    DefaultMutableTreeNode halifax = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Halifax");

    bancos.add(bbva);
    bancos.add(sabadell);
    bancos.add(santander);
    bancos.add(suizo);
    bancos.add(deutche);
    bancos.add(halifax);

    DefaultMutableTreeNode unicaja = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Unicaja Banco");
    DefaultMutableTreeNode caja_rural = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Caja Rural");

    cajas_ahorro.add(unicaja);
    cajas_ahorro.add(caja_rural);

    root.add(bancos);
    root.add(cajas_ahorro);

    jTreeBancos = new JTree(root);
    jTreeBancos.setModel(new javax.swing.tree.DefaultTreeModel(root));
```

Answer (score 0):

En el código fuente todo está debidamente instanciado y estructurado, sin embrago el `JTree` no se ve porque nunca es agregado a la vista (*por lo menos en ese código no se está agregando*), simplemente se necesita la instrucción `add(jTreeBancos);` o `miPanel.add(jTreeBancos);`